# Issues with regex of decimal places

Tags: regex

I've tried a lot to find out the value using my regular expression, but somehow its not working, some of you might help.

```
    $102
    $102.36
    $204.36
```

I am using below regular expression

```
    [$]\\d+[.]\\d{0,2}
```

but this is only fetching the value where decimal is present (for my case 102.36 & 204.36), but for my case decimal is optional, please help me out.

Comment: Yo use `?` quantifier to make a part of your regex pattern optional.

Comment: so instead of fix [.] should I write ?. can you rephrase my regex?

Comment: You should add `?` quantifier to the part that is for decimal part. In your case, from `[.]` till the end.

Comment: Could there possibly be a sign in your number ? and are numbers like `$.23` accepted ? and can there be more than 2 numbers after the decimal point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `?` together with parentheses for the optional part:

```
[$]\\d+([.]\\d{0,2})?
```

Comment: `?` is not an operator.

Comment: How to capture the numbers after the `.` when they are present?

Comment: Since the optional part is surrounded by parentheses, its match will be available as a group. If you want to exclude the dot, you could write is as `(?:[.](\\d{0,2}))?` -- this way, only the digits will be in the group.

Answer (score 0):

`\$([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?))`

dollar sign followed by a number one or more times optionally followed by (a dot followed by a number 1 or more times)

`\$([0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)`

Same but will only match 2dp, the first (not 0th) match class will contain the number.

0th match: all of it (inc $)

1st match: all of the number

2nd match: the decimal point and numbers that follow (if present)

to not capture the 2nd match with Perl flavours or Regex:

`\$([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{2})?)`